# Azure DevOps - Check out current repo in PR triggered SecretScan pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, checkout, pull-request

We would like to do SecretScan as part of PRs when feature branches are merged / PRed into dev.

I was thinking to have the SecretScan pipeline yaml stored in a shared Azure DevOps Project/Repository.

Add the SecretScan pipeline in each of our projects.

And add this as required pipeline for PRs. Instead of having the YAML defining SecretScan in each and every repository.

What I am wondering is, how to check out the current repo (where PR was triggered) during the SecretScan.

The SecretScan at the moment looks like this, but when triggered - it only scans itself - and not the triggering repository.

stages:

```
- stage: SecretScan
  displayName: Scan project for secrets
  jobs:
  - job: Secret_Scan
    displayName: Secret Scan
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    steps:
    - checkout: self
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: 'Use dotnet'
      inputs:
        version: 3.1.x
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: 'Use dotnet'
      inputs:
        version: 5.0.x
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: 'Use dotnet'
      inputs:
        version: 6.0.x
    - task: MicrosoftSecurityDevOps@1
      displayName: 'Microsoft Security DevOps'
      inputs:
          categories: 'secrets'
          break: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your expectation, you may consider using the `SecretScan` YAML as a [template which can be kept in other repositories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#use-other-repositories) from `AnotherProject`.

In my case, I created the `pipelineX` referencing the `azure-pipelines.yml` pipeline definition in the `TestRepo` of `ProjectX`. This YAML definition had used the `SecretScanRepo` from `AnotherProject` as the repository resource, whose symbolic alias was `TemplateRepo`. To use the `SecretScan.yml` in the `TemplateRepo`, I added the template expression of `- template: SecretScan.yml@TemplateRepo`.

**azure-pipelines.yml** in `TestRepo`of `ProjectX`

```
trigger:
- none
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: TemplateRepo
    name: AnotherProject/SecretScanRepo
    type: git
stages:
- template: SecretScan.yml@TemplateRepo
- stage: StageX
  jobs:
  - job: JobX
    steps:
    - script: echo StageX
```

When `pipelineX` was triggered by a PR, the `-checkout: self` step would check out the code from `TestRepo@refs/pull/{PRId}/merge` onto the agent. If you want to use the source code from `TemplateRepo` as well, you can add another checkout step `-checkout: TemplateRepo`. See more information on [Check out multiple repositories in your pipeline - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops).

**SecretScan.yml** in `SecretScanRepo` of `AnotherProject`

```
stages:
- stage: SecretScan
  displayName: Scan project for secrets
  jobs:
  - job: Secret_Scan
    displayName: Secret Scan
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    steps:
    - checkout: self
    - checkout: TemplateRepo
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: 'Use dotnet'
      inputs:
        version: 3.1.x
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: 'Use dotnet'
      inputs:
        version: 5.0.x
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: 'Use dotnet'
      inputs:
        version: 6.0.x
    - task: MicrosoftSecurityDevOps@1
      displayName: 'Microsoft Security DevOps'
      inputs:
          categories: 'secrets'
          break: true
```

[image: MultipleCheckOut]